# Bash sed to read auth into debconf-set-selections for Vagrant VM

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql

I have a `Vagrantfile` that uses a bash script to set up a VM. I can't get the script to set a password for MySQL using `debconf-set-selections` with output from an `.auth` file.

Below is an example of the `.auth` file:

```
# MySQL password
jimmy
```

Below is the script used by Vagrant `bootstrap.sh`:

```
# MySQL password
mypass=$(sed '2q;d' .auth)
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password $mypass"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password $mypass"
```

The error given(twice):

```
==> default: warning: Unknown type jimmy, skipping line 1
```

Comment: Add `#!/bin/bash` to the first line in `bootstrap.sh`, maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi @A.B. thanks for your response, that's already at the top of the script. Perhaps I should have included that above to be a little more concise.

Comment: Last try to guess: `debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password \"$mypass\""`

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem. I'll post it here so anyone who has the same problem won't get stuck.

```
mypass=$(sed '2q;d' .auth)
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password "$mypass
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password "$mypass
```

I didn't pass the type to be expected which was `password`. That is why the script was complaining about the password.

I've also seen a similar answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/19367/scripted-install-of-mysql-on-ubuntu)